# Return value from Javascript function assigned to Label the properties of Label is changing

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In Javscript function i am assigning a value to Label. Value is assigned but the label properties are changing to default values.

```
document.getElementById("Label1").innerText = dispTime;
```

Where **dispTime** is some value in javascript function.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ToolTip="Current Time" ForeColor="BlueViolet" BorderStyle="Ridge" BackColor="ButtonHighlight"></asp:Label>
```

This is how my **Label** defined but after page load the Label properties changing to default values

My Page_Load

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:InIt();", true);
```

My javascript part

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="head1" runat="server">
<title>Time</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function InIt() {
    var dateTime = new Date();
    var hours = dateTime.getHours();
    var minutes = dateTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = dateTime.getSeconds();
    var day;
    if (hours < 11) {
        day = "AM";
    }
    else {
        day = "PM";
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    var dispTime = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + day;
    setTimeout("InIt()", 1000);
    var updatetime = document.getElementById("Label1");
    updatetime.innerText = dispTime;
}
InIt();
</script>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="time" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ToolTip="Current Time" style="background-color:ButtonHighlight; border-style:ridge;"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

assign the value on document.ready of jquery.

If you set the value from `java-script` the value will change again if you have written something on the page load of your `.cs` page.

Comment: I tried this but no use **document.ready("Label1") = dispTime;**

Comment: @Jagadesh can you write your `java-script` function and `page_load` function in you question.

Answer (score 0):

on the pageload event you can use this code to call the javascript function AssignvaluetoLabel() then add the script inside the the function

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(),  "Assign", "AssignvaluetoLabel();", true);
}


<html>
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<script >
function AssignvaluetoLabel()
{
var dispTime="some value";
document.getElementById("Label1").innerText = dispTime;

}
</script>
</head>

 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager  ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use a scriptmanager inside the form also set the RegisterStartupScript property also

Comment: I am getting the value in javascript. I will edit the full code that I did.

Comment: I am also getting the value but the problem is Label properties are changing to default value after page_Load()

Comment: it will not update the label. because in your code it initialise he value on the init method on javascript. yhat is the problem. rewrite the ethod as I given you in my last answer.it will be worked.because you are calling the javascript from the pageload. then it willnot change the value of label in pageload. pls listen the code carefully. you will get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code with adding jquery file reference in your page.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ToolTip="Current Time" ForeColor="BlueViolet" BorderStyle="Ridge" BackColor="ButtonHighlight"></asp:Label>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            TestFunction("testvalue");
        });

        function TestFunction(dispTime) {
            $("#<%= Label1.ClientID %>").text(dispTime);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your updated code...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="head1" runat="server"  >
<title>Time</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function AssignvaluetoLabel() {
    var dateTime = new Date();
    var hours = dateTime.getHours();
    var minutes = dateTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = dateTime.getSeconds();
    var day;
    if (hours < 11) {
        day = "AM";
    }
    else {
        day = "PM";
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }



  document.getElementById("Label1").innerText = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + day;

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

   <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="time" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ToolTip="Current Time" style="background-color:ButtonHighlight; border-style:ridge;"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "Assign", "AssignvaluetoLabel();", true);
}
```